# How to repeat the Code and not close after 1 time running

Tags: python

I have a code here, my problem is that it runs 1 time and close and I want that after the last time.sleep() it starts over again:

```
import requests
import datetime
import random
import urllib.parse
import webbrowser
import time
import subprocess


while true:

THE WHOLE CODE

time.sleep(50)
```

like this it dont even run the whole code its like running only the first line after while true.
I want that it starts code from Up and go down and after time.sleep it go up again etc...

Thx a lot

I tryed with

```
while true:
for x in range(100):
```

etc... but at end it dont start from beginning and turn off after 1 time.

Comment: What is your actual code. This example won't run and doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: The syntax of even your pseudocode and the two lines of python is incorrect for the purpose you state.  In python, indentation matters.  In fact, your two lines of python code will not run, as it contains at least two errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be formatted as follows:

```
import time    

while True:
    # some code here
    time.sleep(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Seems like the issue is with "THE WHOLE CODE" part of your loop.

```
while True:
    do_something()
```

Will keep repeating do_something() infinitely, unless an interrupt happens or a break statement is reached inside of the loop. If this is not the case, there might be an issue with the rest of your code - perhaps one of the lines is stuck and never completes successfully, which stops the rest of the loop from ever executing? You could try debugging, place some print statements throughout the loop.

##### Possible Blocking?

I see that you imported subprocess, this could be the culprit. If you start a subprocess.run() and the process takes some time to finish or runs continuously, it'll stop your code from progressing forward. In such case, you can instead use subprocess.Popen, which is non-blocking and will start the subprocess in the background.

```
new_process = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "my-app.jar"], start_new_session=True)
```

or to get rid of output

```
new_process = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "my-app.jar"], start_new_session=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting your whole code or at least debugging and posting the problematic part of it, otherwise I don't think anyone can help any more than this.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with python personally, but I believe the same logic would apply. are you holding a bool value to be tested in the while loop? such as

bool test = true

while (test)

{

do something

if (some parameter is met to end it)

test = false

}

the while loop should continue running until the parameter is met to change test to false, which exits the loop.